# How do I write test class for the below code?

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I am new to Salesforce and I was playing around. So I have a vf page in which I am displaying a modal and closing it once its done. The functionality is working well. I'm just stuck at how to write a test class for it. Can anybody help me out here?

```
public class TrialClass {
    public boolean displayPopup {get; set;}
    public void closePopup() {   
        displayPopup = false;
    }
     public void showPopup() {     
        displayPopup = true;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question doesn't state what you have tried, or where you are stuck. However, I would suggest you try working through the trailhead for apex tests to get a start on how to write a test class for your code (if you haven't yet): https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro